# Faraday induction law - surface clarification

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Faraday's law states,
$$emf = \oint \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{l}  = - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \int \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{s}$$

The typical surface we see used to elucidate this law is a single-turn coil of wire like below (purple).  Where the surface (green) is a 2-dimensional surface in the plane of the coil that is perfectly normal to the B field everywhere.

[image]

**My question is about the choice of surface area**.  I am fairly sure (and @RobJeffries [answer here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/226154/are-there-any-geometric-restrictions-on-the-line-and-surface-elements-in-the-max) apparently supports) that the surface can take many different shapes as long as it is bounded by the coil.  **Is my understanding correct**?

For example, if i use any of the following surfaces (assuming i can properly handle the integration and dot product on the R.H.S.) i will get the same result for *emf* as if i used the above surface.

In this case i just "grew" a hollow cylinder up where the coil (dashed black line) defines the open bottom end (the orange surface is not involved in the surface integral on R.H.S.).

[image]

In this case below my surface area is the inside of a garbage bag filled with air with the bag opening being perfectly defined by the coil.

[image]

In this last case, the surface is the inside of a cone with the open bottom defined by the coil.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is valid for all *smooth* surfaces limited by the loop, according to the [Kelvin-Stokes theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Stokes_theorem). It is ok for the garbage bag, but I am afraid it is necessary to put some small radius at the sharp edges of the other 2 surfaces.

Comment: So, for example, the sharp transition between the cylinder side and top would be a problem because it is not smooth transition?

Comment: I think in both the problematic cases, we could take the limit when the relief radius go to zero.